# Difference Between Two Columns Without Joins?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have two tables. One table for the current location of moving vehicles (name, lat, long). The other table contains the location of cities (name, lat, long). The tables share no common values between each other.

I want to find which city is each cars closest location. How would I do this?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: How is your geography\geometry data looks like. Is it postGIS geoms or WKT (something like 'Point( 0 0)' ) or just columns lat long ?
Do you have PostGIS installed on your server?
Pls, add some more info (data structure, some rows from tables) will be much easier to give you proper solution

Comment: Actually it is simple like `select * from vehicles, lateral (select * from cities order by distance(city, vehicle) limit 1)`. What you need is the `distance(point, point)` function.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer myself, here's what it looks like for those that stumble in here with the same problem:

```
drop table if exists t_loc_foun;
create temp table t_loc_foun as
with a as 
    (select
        car, latest_lat, latest_lon 
    from 
        t_car_unique),
b as 
    (select 
        lat, lon, lo_city_code 
    from 
        as_poi)
select 
    *, sqrt((latest_lat - lat)^2) as lat_diff, sqrt((latest_lon - lon)^2) as lon_diff 
from 
    a, b;
```

With clause is allowing me to put the rows together and then subtract all the values in the columns. Works quickly in my case where it ends up with 1,000,000 rows. Maybe a more optimal solution out there for more.

Comment: What SRID is your data? If it is 4326 then your results will be in degrees and it will be extremly inacurate to translate it to meters. If you have your data in srid 3857 (metric geometry system used by google) then it will work.
Stil i advice to instal postgis if possible and use it for projects with geometry/geography data is postgres.